# scss no se aplica en jsfiddle

Tags: css, jsfiddle, scss

Tengo un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javatlacati/6r97oth7/1/) y traté de aplicarle estilos con [scss](/questions/tagged/scss) pero no se ven aplicados.

Los resultados deberían de verse como en [este otro](https://jsfiddle.net/javatlacati/7pncvvoz/1/).

¿Por que no está funcionando la conversión de [scss](/questions/tagged/scss) a [css](/questions/tagged/css)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente el compilador de 
*SCSS* que usa [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) parece no soportar la función `random()`

No encuentro una fuente confiable que mencione esto, sin embargo si quitas todas las llamadas a `random()` el resto del CSS se genera correctamente